# what is the time complexity to check if a dictionary has a key?

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

According to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity given a dictionary `D` the operation 
`D[k]` is constant.
What is the complexity of `k in D` ? Is this still constant?

Answer (score 7):

Membership testing has the exact same cost as retrieving an item, so O(1).

That's only logical, because in order to return the value of a given key, you first need to determine if it is in the dictionary. If retrieving a key takes constant time, then determining if it is in the dictionary in the first place can only ever take constant time, too.